# Sweave/R Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: r, sweave

R 3.0.2, Mac OS 10.7.5, MacTeX2013

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

test test test

\end{document}
```

gives this line in the log file

```
/Users/ian/Library/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave/tex/latex/Sweave.sty:27: Undefined co
ntrol sequence.

l.27 \DefineVerbatimEnvironment
                               {Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
?
```

Compilation without Sweave package is fine. With same setup on other machines, everything is fine. I guess it has something to do with missing fonts on this specific machine but after much googling, I am still stuck. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `fancyvrb` LaTeX package installed on your machine ?

Comment: kpsewhich fancyvrb.sty /Users/ian/Library/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave/tex/latex/fancyvrb.sty

Comment: And if you add `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` ?

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Have you tried running it with `knitr::knit` instead of sweave?

Comment: @Thomas just tried, basic example above works! However, an example with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} gives Error: test.tex:61: Font T1/cmtt/m/n/10=ectt1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. I have add similar errors with Sweave during my attempts to fix original problem so maybe same underlying problem with fonts in both Sweave/knitr? thanks

Comment: any answer? still facing the same issue